# Windows User control form

Tags: windows, winforms, user-controls

I am creating one user control in windows form. It is some data entry form. The application opens in minimize mode initially. And the from looks good in minimization mode. But when i maximize the form is not getting filled up. I mean the there is lot of room in maximize mode. The form should grow size according to minimize or maximize. The form has tab control, group box and grid view. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly, check your anchor points of the controls on your form. Also, check that form controls are set to grow and shrink, as you see fit. The combination of the two may fix your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for the quick, to-thespot answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i am pretty new to dotnet. let me try your suggestions and will get back. thanks a lot though.